# Trying to understand Kol Hanearim

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot

Where does the custom of Kol Hanearim, were all children stand near the person getting an aliah and are covered with a tallis-canopy, come from? What, if anything, is it a segulah for? Why is it done on shmini atzeret/simchas torah?

Comment: Nice question, +1 ......you have a lot of rep for an unregistered user! You may want to consider consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features (including all your points, as well as [control over your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/266359), so you won't be able to edit them, nor accept answers for them) ....just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

During Simchas Torah we have the minhag of giving everybody an aliyah. Most shuls will call up boys under bar mitzvah who are old enough to know what thay are doing/ The final aliyah is considered a zechus because the person says the bracha with all of the children around him to show that they too are included in the mitzvah.

By this, I mean that he is introducing the children to the Torah and impressing them with importance of the Torah. He is showing them that they are part of the kahal and that they too can be part of the inheritence of the Jewish people. That is also part of the reason that we repeat the bracha of Yaakov (Hamal'ach hagoel ... ) The person who brings them to the Torah and the bracha of Yaakov can be considered to have a segulah of meriting children and grandchildren just as Yaakov Avinu did (as shown in the quote below).

Another reason is that there are statements that someone who brings bracha on someone else can then receive that bracha. For example, someone who arranges shidduchim for others merits his (or her) own children finding shidduchim. Someone davening for refuah of someone else receives a refuah. Here bringing the children under the "chupah" of Torah merits his own children and grandchildren being brought under the "chupah" of Torah (and of course he has to have some for this to happen).

In Kol Hanearim under the Talis, he actually shows them that they are as dear to him as his own children.

Another point is that it is similar to the mitzvah of Hakhel in which the children who are too young to understand are brought as well. This last is a point that I thought of myself as I have not seen it mentioned. The similarity just struck me.

The following is an exerpt that illustrates this point. Follow the link for the whole article.

[All the Children](http://www.jewishjournal.com/articles/item/all_the_children_19981009)

> One year, however, the auction for Kol Hanearim in my synagogue was
>   unusually competitive. When finally over, I asked the man who fiercely
>   bid the highest, why he vied for this honor.
>
> Surprised by my question, he replied as if it were self-evident: "The
>   one who supervises scores of little children crowded under the tallit,
>   reciting the same blessing Jacob uttered over his grandchildren, is
>   himself guaranteed Jewish grandchildren. Could I want less for
>   myself?"
>
> These words come to me again and again, whenever I contemplate the
>   unique Torah portion, Vezot Haberakha, the only parasha not identified
>   with a specific Shabbat. Rather, it is reserved for the joyous Simchat
>   Torah holiday, with its unique Kol Hanearim ceremony, and as such
>   deserves close analysis.
>
> The Talmud, in Sukkah 42a, referring to Vezot Haberakha, provides a
>   provocative comment: "Our rabbis taught: A minor who is able to speak,
>   his father must teach him Torah.... What could be meant by Torah? Rav
>   Hamnuna replied, the Scriptural verse [Deuteronomy 33:4], 'Moses
>   commanded us a law, an inheritance of the congregation of Jacob.'"
>
> Certainly these lessons are themes that the beautiful Kol Hanearim
>   ceremony emphasizes. First, each child has a right to Torah, an
>   inheritance that comes with birth.
>
> Second, Kol Hanearim suggests that Torah requires effort. Neither
>   children nor adults will acquire knowledge unless they work at
>   studying Torah. If they put in the effort, they will be rewarded with
>   the greatest gift: the Torah itself.
>
> And, finally, we must appreciate that a Jewish life must include the
>   community of fellow Jews. The little children are blessed as part of
>   an entire group -- part of a future community -- because Torah can't
>   be lived in isolation. Instead, our blessing emphasizes the need for
>   everyone to be involved with the Jewish community, for only together
>   do we comprise the congregation that both Vezot Haberakha and Simchat
>   Torah celebrate.

Comment: Why is saying a bracha in the proximity of children a zechus?

Comment: @DoubleAA I expanded on the subject of the zechus as shown in the exerpt that I quoted. I hope that it explains what I meant.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect saying something someone else did is a Segulah for having similar amounts of progeny as they did? (Or some other reason for asserting that this is a _bona fide_ Segulah?)

Comment: @DoubleAA see the quote and I have seen other references which I do not have available. Also it is like giving a bracha to the children that they should grow up in the Torah.

Comment: Is "giving a bracha to the children that they should grow up in the Torah" a Segulah for having grandchildren? Whence do you know this?

Comment: @DoubleAA My comment was based on having learned that someone who acts to cause a bracha on someone else (such as setting up shidduchim) will receive that bracha himself. One of the cases that I saw was a someone who had been having trouble finding a shidduch for her daughter. When she got involved in finding shidduchim for others, her daughter became engaged. Other cases involved having children, and so forth. This concept forms the basis of many stories of this type such as are written by Pesach Krohn.

Comment: The תורה צוה לנו משה connection would be stronger if we used rishon, or a later iteration of rishon, for kol hanearim.  I've only seen that done once, and it was because we were getting too close to the naar's naptime.